# BUILD ERROR 'copy-resources' was specified in an execution, but not found in the plug in

Tags: maven

Build Error 'copy-resources' was specified in an execution but not found in the plugin

Below is the code in my pom.xml

Can any one help on this error

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>META-INF</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: is "validate" not a rather early phase for this plugin? "process-resources" sounds more likely. Maybe the id for the execution cannot be the same as the goal? Because in all looks quite ok.

Comment: I tired to change goal name as - process-resources but getting below error.                                                                   [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 'process-resources' was specified in an execution, but not found in the p
lugin                                                                 <goals>
       <goal>process-resources</goal>
      </goals>

Comment: no I think the goal is correct. At least looking at the docs: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/plugin-info.html it looks ok. what I meant is using a different <id> and also execute the plugin in a later phase than validate. If you just want to do filtering you can also configure this via the <resource> section in the build: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: Fixed : changed the maven version 2.0.8 to 2.2.1. problem with maven 2.0.8 version only.